# Экранировать часть javascript для совместимости со старыми браузерами

Tags: javascript, 1с

Есть две страницы, которые используют один js файл. Одна страница для основной версии сайта, другая адаптирована для браузера 1С.
Для функционала основной версии сайта добавили [метод из стандарта ES6/ES2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function), который не поддерживается встроенным браузером 1С. Из-за чего при загрузке выводится сообщение об ошибке синтаксиса.
Подскажите как можно экранировать часть кода js-файла от устаревшего браузера? Плодить несколько js с делением по версионности, мне кажется, не правильным подходом.

Comment: Какой метод? Параметры по умолчанию? Там же в ответе указано кроссбраузерное решение

Comment: Может воспользоваться сторонними библиотеками?

Comment: Anton Shchyrov, метод свой, да параметры по умолчанию. Городить что-то вроде `a = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a : 42;` считаю совершенно нечитабельным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно ничего экранировать. Хорошая практика - делать проверку на наличие новой ES6-фичи и если ее нет, то добавлять ее реализацию вручную. Для проверки поддержки параметров по умолчанию можно использовать код [как здесь](https://www.bram.us/2016/10/31/checking-if-a-browser-supports-es6/). Но на практике придется условно переопределять все функции, где используются параметры по умолчанию. Проще тогда уж везде реализовывать параметры по-умолчанию по старинке как в ES5:

```
function (a) {
  a = (a !== undefined) ? a : 42;
}
```

Comment: а как проверить наличие возможности добавлять значения по умолчанию в методе?

Comment: Не заметил, что речь идет про параметры по умолчанию. Что касается проверки, можно выкрутиться как описано [вот тут](https://www.bram.us/2016/10/31/checking-if-a-browser-supports-es6/). Но на практике, если нужна поддержка старых браузеров, придется условно переопределять все функции, где используются параметры по умолчанию. Проще тогда уж везде использовать по старинке как в ES5.

Comment: подкорректируйте ответ, отмечу как решение

Comment: Подкорректировал